# Samsung Android phone rendering chess unicode as Emoji?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, special-characters

I'm developing a [javascript implementation][1] of Singularity Chess and I'm having a really weird issue with rendering on Samsung phones. Samsung phones render unicode chess characters as what appear to be a custom Emoji representation, as opposed to the plain text version. This would not be a problem, except for the fact that the Emoji set has only black pieces.

Is there a nice fix for this, or do I have to use the User Agent string to dynamically switch to a different display method such as SVG?

Comment: Why not simply use sprites or svg by default? Using a font always runs the risk not showing what you want.

Comment: I decided to go with text rendering because it made asset management easier and it was a lot less work than developing or finding images. It's also way less complicated in the code to store a character and fill/stroke it on the canvas in a given color than it would be to juggle SVGs for the same feature set.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `U+FE0E VARIATION SELECTOR-15` after each chess piece to force them to render them as text. For reference, `U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16` will force characters to render as emoji.

`U+270C` ✌

`U+270C` `U+FE0E` ✌︎

`U+270C` `U+FE0F` ✌️

Further reading: [Emoji Variants on Unicode.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224180412/https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-variants.html), [The Secret Life of Variation Selectors on BabelStone](https://web.archive.org/web/20170311055113/https://babelstone.blogspot.com/2007/06/secret-life-of-variation-selectors.html)

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. I can't believe I had never heard of these before.

Comment: The link is dead.